# How to write this Regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract data from string I have but I don't know how to do it with regex.
The string is:

```
validate[required,maxSize[255],....]
```

'....' means it maybe another digits and letters.
So what is the regex I should use to extract the 255 value ? (the maxsize value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the string you can be really lazy and simply match on `/maxSize\[(\d+)\]/`

```
> /maxSize\[(\d+)\]/.exec('validate[required,maxSize[255],foo]')[1]
'255'
```

If you want to ensure it's inside `validate[...]` it will become much, much harder unless you safely know it will occur only once and there won't be additional `[..]` blocks inside:

```
> /validate\[[^\]]*maxSize\[(\d+)\].*\]/.exec(
    'validate[required,maxSize[255],foo,bar]')[1]
'255'
```

If the mentioned restrictions are not acceptable, you cannot do it with regexes - they are not powerful enough to match things such as properly nested brackets. In case you are trying to parse the full validation rule, consider using a proper parser. In that case I'd extract the `validate[...]` part first by searching for `validate[` and then proceeding one char by another while counting `[` and `]` occurrences to see when the first one closes. Then I'd split the string between those brackets using `,` as the delimiter and *then* use either the parser I already have or a regex to extract the length. Since you could pretty much reuse the parser I'd go with that one; it could even give you a nicely structured objects for the whole validation rule (even ones with multiple parameters) instead of just a bunch of strings/integers.

Comment: maxSize\[(\d+)\] this one was enough